# Looping over distinct values

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

Given a variable which returns a list of distinct States using the distinct-values() function, is there a way to tokenize the variable in a for-each loop?

```
<States>
<State>AL</State>
<State>AL</State>
<State>NM</State>
</States>
```

The following variable returns AL and NM, but I can't iterate over it using for-each.  Is there a way around this?

```
<xsl:variable name="FormStates" select="distinct-values(States/State)"/>
  <xsl:for-each select="$FormStates">
```

XSLT 2.0 ok.

Comment: As always, it is not clear at all what problem you have. Learn to provide: 1. The source XML document. 2. The wanted result. 3. The required properties of the transformation.

Comment: I have voted to CLOSE this question. It is not really a question -- no question is being asked. The problem is not defined and is not clear.

Comment: Sorry, I hopefully clarified the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `distinct-values()` function returns a sequence of values which you should be able to iterate over. The result is so to speak "tokenized".

`fn:distinct-values('AL', 'AL', 'NL')` returns the sequence `('AL', 'NL')`.

If you output the variable with `xsl:value-of` it will return the string "AL NL" only because the default sequence separator for `xsl:value-of` is a single space character. This is something you could change with the `@separator` attribute:

**Input**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<States>
  <State>AL</State>
  <State>AL</State>
  <State>NM</State>
</States>
```

**XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="FormStates" select="distinct-values(States/State)"/>
    <xsl:comment>xsl:value-of</xsl:comment>
    <xsl:value-of select="$FormStates" separator=":"/>
    <xsl:comment>xsl:for-each</xsl:comment>
    <xsl:for-each select="$FormStates">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      <xsl:text>:</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--xsl:value-of-->
AL:NM
<!--xsl:for-each-->
AL:NM:
```

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't aware of the separator attribute.   I ended up building a delimited string and using tokenize(), but I will go back and clean it up.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an **XSLT 1.0** solution that I've used in the past.

```
  <xsl:template match="/">           
    <ul> 
      <xsl:for-each select="//State[not(.=preceding::*)]">
        <li>
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </li>   
      </xsl:for-each>            
    </ul>
  </xsl:template>
```

Returns:

```
<ul xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <li>AL</li>
  <li>NM</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

In theory it should work; are you sure the XPath given to the `distinct-values` function is correct? The code you've given requires that the `States` element is a sibling of the `forms` element.

You could insert `<xsl:value-of select="count($FormStates)">` immediately after the variable declaration to confirm if it is being set properly.